# Sql - How many people earn min and max salary?

Tags: sql

I have a table with Employees, Departments and Salaries and I would like to get min and max salaries per department (what is just min/max with group by on department), **but how to count how many Employees earn that min and max salary per department?**

```
Select Department,
       Count(distinct EmployeeID) as Employees,
       Min(Salary) as Min,
       Max(Salary) as Max
  From Employees
 Group by Department;
```

Comment: Hint:  You need a subquery (which is your query) and another `join`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your query as a subquery for the following one :

```
Select Department, count(*) as "Count People"
  From Employees
 Where (Department,Salary) IN
   (
    Select Department, Min(Salary)
      From Employees
     Group by Department
     Union all 
    Select Department, Max(Salary)
      From Employees
     Group by Department
    )
 Group by Department;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ZFHPH9575)

Comment: I am sql beginner, maybe you can clarify a little more, how your query will get me min and max earners count?

Comment: @Dude135 In the subquery, we detect  min and max salaries grouped by depts. Whichever values the salaries have, they remain in the restricted set of data by `in` operator. Only those of min and max values are compared by `in` operator and again they need to be claasifed with respect to the depts to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need 2 distinct values for the counters of minimum and maximum salaries of each department:

```
SELECT t1.Department, t1.MinCounter, t2.MaxCounter FROM
    (SELECT t.Department, COUNT(*) AS MinCounter 
    FROM 
        (SELECT Department, MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary FROM Employees
        GROUP BY Department) AS t 
    INNER JOIN Employees 
    ON (t.MinSalary = Employees.Salary) AND (t.Department = Employees.Department)
    GROUP BY t.Department) AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT t.Department, COUNT(*) AS MaxCounter 
    FROM 
        (SELECT Department, MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary FROM Employees
        GROUP BY Department) AS t 
    INNER JOIN Employees 
    ON (t.MaxSalary = Employees.Salary) AND (t.Department = Employees.Department)
    GROUP BY t.Department) AS t2
ON t1.Department = t2.Department
```

The above query consists of 2 subqueries joined by `Department`, each of which fetches the counter of the minimum and the maximum salary per department.  
 If you also want included in the query the amounts of the minimum and the maximum salary per department, then check this:

```
SELECT t1.Department, t1.MinSalary, t1.MinCounter, t2.MaxSalary, t2.MaxCounter
FROM 
    (SELECT t.Department, t.MinSalary, COUNT(*) AS MinCounter 
    FROM (SELECT Department, MIN(Salary) AS MinSalary FROM Employees 
    GROUP BY Department)  AS t 
    INNER JOIN Employees 
    ON (t.Department = Employees.Department) 
    AND (t.MinSalary = Employees.Salary) 
    GROUP BY t.Department, MinSalary)  AS t1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT t.Department, t.MaxSalary, COUNT(*) AS MaxCounter 
    FROM (SELECT Department, MAX(Salary) AS MaxSalary FROM Employees 
    GROUP BY Department)  AS t 
    INNER JOIN Employees 
    ON (t.Department = Employees.Department) 
    AND (t.MaxSalary = Employees.Salary) 
    GROUP BY t.Department, MaxSalary)  AS t2 
ON t1.Department = t2.Department
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the min and max salaries in a subquery, then count how many employees have those salaries in an outer query, like so:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b89ac6b76112bf7db65ce6e37754198b

```
select agg.*
, count(case when e.Salary = agg.MinSalary then 1 end) EmployeesWithMin
, count(case when e.Salary = agg.MaxSalary then 1 end) EmployeesWithMax
from
(
    select Department
    , count(1) EmployeesInDepartment
    , min(Salary) MinSalary
    , max(Salary) MaxSalary
    from Employees
    group by Department
) agg
inner join Employees e
on e.Department = agg.department
and e.Salary in (agg.MaxSalary, agg.MinSalary)
group by agg.Department
, agg.EmployeesInDepartment
, agg.MinSalary
, agg.MaxSalary
```

Or an alternative approach:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8a5e539fcd3e5985d44f86b1e331f030

```
select agg.Department
, min(agg.MinSalary) MinSalary
, max(agg.MaxSalary) MaxSalary
, count(case when Salary = MinSalary then 1 end) EmployeesWithMin
, count(case when Salary = MaxSalary then 1 end) EmployeesWithMax
from
(
    select Department
    , min(Salary) over (partition by Department) MinSalary
    , max(Salary) over (partition by Department) MaxSalary
    , Salary
    from Employees
) agg
group by agg.Department
```

The former may be simpler to understand for a beginner.  The latter is less verbose, so easier to read.  i.e. Pick whichever you're more comfortable supporting / whichever makes most sense to you.

In terms of performance, the second performed slightly better for my sample data; but a number of variables may influence this (number of rows, spread of values, availability of indexes), so it's best to test on data as similar to real-world as possible if you need to pick the optimal query.

Let me know if any of the methods used here aren't familiar to you and I can add explanations as required.